# Import matter-js in typescript project

Tags: typescript, matter.js

I found this file :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/matter-js

i execute this line :

npm install --save @types/matter-js

In root ts file i got error message :

> 'Matter' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module.
>   Consider adding an import instead.

Code looks like :

```
///<reference path="matter-js.d.ts"/>

import Ioc from "./libs/ioc";
let master = new Ioc();
console.log(master);
console.log(Matter);
```

Error in browser:

> app.ts:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: Matter is not defined

Did i need to load matter-js.js lib ?

If i put  :

```
import matter from 'matter-js'
```

i get :

> Module ''matter-js'' has no default export.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to load it using `import * as matter from 'matter-js'`, that should work.

Comment: I removed this line ///<reference path="matter-js.d.ts"/>  . No need at all now.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do

```
var Matter = require('matter-js');
```

or

```
import { Engine, World, Body, Bodies, Constraint } from 'matter-js';
```

The `@types/matter-js` is missing the `Common` class, but maybe you shouldn't use that anyway.  If you really need it, you can add this to the index.d.ts in the package,

```
export class Common {
    static extend(obj:any, deep?:boolean): any;
    static clone(obj:any, deep?:boolean): any;
    static keys(obj:any): any;
    static values(obj:any): any;
    static get(obj:any, path:string, begin:number, end:number): any;
    static set(obj:any, path:string, val:any, begin:number, end:number): any;
    static shuffle(array:any[]): any;
    static choose(choices:any[]): any;
    static isElement(obj:any):boolean;
    static isArray(obj:any):boolean;
    static isFunction(obj:any):boolean;
    static isPlainObject(obj:any):boolean;
    static isString(obj:any):boolean;
    static clamp(value:number, min:number, max:number):number;
    static sign(value:number): number;   
    static now(): number;
    static random(min?:number, max?:number): number;
    static colorToNumber(colorString:string): number;
    static log(...objs:any[]): void;
    static info(...objs:any[]): void;
    static warn(...objs:any[]): void;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the typescript lib seems outdated. Last commit 2 years ago. Parameters that should be optional are instead required in the typescript definitions...

Answer (score 2):

I load the matter.js library with a script tag. Did you forget that?

```
<script src="js/matter.min.js"></script>
```

And I installed the typings with

```
npm install @types/matter-js
```

Comment: It is correct but if i already use ts, webpack i wanted to get absolute all app files from src/ to build/ based on dependency...

Comment: Just go install the types `npm i @types/matter-js -D`.

Answer (score 0):

I got errors for my matterjs import until I deleted my `node_modules` and ran `npm install` again. Then the problems went away. Ended up with the following:

```
import * as Matter from 'matter-js';
```