# Combining typescript with matterjs in webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, matter.js

I have a question on how to combine matterjs with typescript in webpack. When I try it now the problem is that I cannot export Matter from matter-js.

I tried using this npm [Import matter-js in typescript project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734671/import-matter-js-in-typescript-project).

But when I try to import Matter it says the there is no export module.

Someone experiences with this?

My import

```
import  Matter  from "matter-js";
```

> Module '"c:/code/platformer/platformer_typescript/node_modules/@types/matter-js/index"' has no default export.

This is my error message.

Comment: Please show your current code which attempts to import Matter, and the _exact_ error message you receive, otherwise it's not as easy to help

Answer (score 0):

I guess just install the `typings` for `matterjs` library no?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings